# Excel 2010 MS Date Picker on worksheet was working suddenly not working

Tags: windows-7, datepicker, excel-2010, 32-bit, ocx

I run 32-bit Excel 2010 in 32-bit Windows 7. I have been using the "Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0 (SP6)" in multiple workbooks for more than a year now. Yesterday I opened the master template workbook that I do my in-progress coding within and the Date Picker has **suddenly** stopped functioning completely. In the places on the worksheet where the control is there is instead shown an image of a few nonsensical symbols.
I have tried using regsvr32 to register 3 different versions of Mscomct2.ocx, rebooting my system each time. I've tried 2 versions of the SP6 ocx, and 1 version of the SP4 ocx. This did not change anything. The registered control is now shown as (SP6) and is still not functioning on my system.
Also, when I try to manually insert a new control of this type on a worksheet I get the completely useless "Cannot insert object." error.
I have very recently installed one piece of software that I am imagining may have caused the problem, it is called "Solid Essential 8.0" by Cabinet Vision. However, if this software overwrote the ocx wouldn't my overwriting and registering a new version of the ocx fix the problem? Or is there something else that I am missing for this control to function correctly?

I have searched for an answer on this and for each posting I have found I have tried the solution but it has not been fixed. When the suggestion doesn't fix the problem they usually suggest using a completely different method. What I want is for someone to explain how to fix the control itself- do not tell me to use a different method, I will do so if no one can tell me how to fix the control that is already in place. These controls work just fine on every other system in our office- everyone else sees the controls just fine and can use them as intended. This is why I am determined to fix the control issue, not use a different method just because *my* system is broken.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i know this is very old, but i resolved a similar msconctl.ocx error by adding my file location as a `trusted location`

Answer (score 0):

According to some posts two binaries need to be registered:

```
@%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32 MSCOMCTL.OCX
@%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32 MSCOMCT2.OCX
```

Comment: Both have been registered, I re-registered them and have the same problem.